# Validation in VF unexpected

Tags: visualforce

I have a VisualForce page with a number of fields that I have marked as *required*.

My issue is that I would like to execute an action in the controller without causing the validation errors to show. At the moment I have buttons that trigger action functions to execute, but with no DML operations, yet the validation errors still show.

Exactly what is triggering the validation errors?

Many thanks

**Edit - Example Code**

```
<apex:repeat value="{!addresses}" var="addr">
    <apex:inputField required="true" value="{!addr.Street__c}" />
    <!-- more address elements here -->
    <apex:commandButton value="Delete" action="{!deleteAddress}">
        <apex:param assignTo="{!addrId}" value="{!addr.Id}" />
    </apex:commandButton>
</apex:repeat>


public List<Address__c> addresses {get; set;}

public PageReference deleteAddress() {
    // Find address to delete using addrId and delete
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like required fields missing, as the validation rules won't execute until you use DML to write the record to the database.

The way around this is to place your action functions and their associated inputs inside action regions.  When you execute the action function, only the input present inside the action region will be sent as part of the postback - essentially it makes the action region its own mini form.  Any other inputs will remain on the screen (unless you overwrite them by rerendering) but won't be sent back to the controller.

See the docs at: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_actionRegion.htm

Based on the code now posted, the issue is that you have the required attribute set to true for the input fields.  This means that the form cannot be posted without values present.  You should still be able to put the command buttons inside their own action regions, in which case no other information would be posted back and the required fields would not cause errors.  Note that you will also need to specify a rerender attribute on the commandbutton, otherwise the parameter will be null - this is a bug in Visualforce that has been kicking around for a while now.

If you can't go that route, I'd look to decorate the field with the required red bar and handle the validation server side.

Comment: Hi Bob thanks for your reply. I've added a code example to my post to clarify. I'm expecting the controller method to find the right address to delete and then refresh the page, but the standard validation messages appear. Also, the page does not refresh when I set the commandButton immediate attribute to true.

Comment: When you set immediate to true, that will discard anything you have input, essentially just resetting the page to its original state.  I've updated my answer to reflect your latest code.

Answer (score 3):

All the validations are get fired as soon as your form get submitted to controller. In your case when you click on button it submits your form to controller that's why all validations are getting fired.

If you don't want to get called all these validation the use "Immidiate" attribute of button. set immediate=true.

Comment: Immediate=true will also discard any data input by the user.

Comment: correct. in that case will have to use actionRegion tag to submit some part of data rather than entire form